Is it mentioned in Mahabharata that Pandavas went to Kedarnath?
This answer mentions that Pandavas went to Kedar Tirtha. This is described in Siva Purana. The description of Kedarnath Jyotirlinga mentions this event.
Is it also described in Mahabharata? I mean, maybe not the entire story. But, is there any hint in Mahabharata that Pandavas did go to the Kedara region?

In Mahabharata it's mentioned that Pandavas visited the ashrama of Nara and Narayana which is in Badarinath.

"There the pious (Yudhishthira) beheld the hermitage of Nara and
Narayana, beautified by the Bhagirathi and worshipped by the gods and
the celestial sages. And seeing that hermitage inhabited by the
Brahmarshis and containing fruits dropping honey, the Pandavas were
filled with delight."


Section CXLIV, Tirtha Yatra Parva, Mahabharata.


Yes, Nara Narayana and Badrinath are also mentioned in the Kedarnath jyotirlinga story. Thanks.
